# The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'ConfirmedPasswordValidationError'

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, getter

When I want to get name from confirm_password file, it gives this error: `The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'ConfirmedPasswordValidationError'.`

Actually I did the same things for email and password, but here somethings wrong.

my confirmPasswordInputField codes here:

```
Widget confirmPasswordInputField() {

      return BlocBuilder<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.confirmPassword != current.confirmPassword,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return AuthTextField(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            hint: 'Confirm Password',
            isPasswordField: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            **error: state.confirmPassword.error?.name,**(here)
            onChanged: (confirmPassword) =>
                context.read<SignUpCubit>().confirmPasswordChanged(confirmPassword),
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

And also my confirm_password file which is mentioned on above by me, here:

```
    enum ConfirmedPasswordValidationError {
      invalid,
      mismatch,
    }
    
    class ConfirmPassword extends FormzInput<String, ConfirmedPasswordValidationError> {
      final String password;
    
      const ConfirmPassword.pure({
        this.password = ''
      }) : super.pure('');
    
      const ConfirmPassword.dirty({
        required this.password,
        String value = ''
      }) : super.dirty(value);
    
      @override
      ConfirmedPasswordValidationError? validator(String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return ConfirmedPasswordValidationError.invalid;
        }
        return password == value
            ? null
            : ConfirmedPasswordValidationError.mismatch;
      }
    }
    
    extension Explanation on ConfirmedPasswordValidationError {
      String? get name {
        switch(this) {
          case ConfirmedPasswordValidationError.mismatch:
            return 'passwords must match';
          default:
            return null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here I defined the getter with a name ‘name’. But when I call it, it gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
import 'package:bloc_login/domain/auth_models/confirm_password.dart';
```

Do not forget the import your packages..